# How to search data and return row number?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to search x for example through a sheet of data. I thought of using Match function but match function only look up to only one column. x could be anywhere in that sheet, so is that any function or anything which can return the row number which can search all data?

I have added codes in the excel and now the error of subscript out of range is appearing. I am not really sure if I did my find function correctly

```
Dim r As range 
With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:DZU")
    Set r = .Find(What:="U1")
End With
```

Comment: yes, Google `Find` , or `Range.Find` you''' get plenty of results.

Comment: If you have a Range, you can always find the row number: Range.Row

Comment: @ShaiRado, I used the find function on the excel sheet itself but it couldn't find it. But when i used the find & select, excel could find it. Don't understand why...

Comment: @RachelChia please share your code attempt and worksheet. so we can take a look

Comment: @RachelChia see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below using the `Find` function to look for `"U1"` in Columns "A:DZU".

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindX()

Dim FndRng As Range

With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:DZU")
    Set FndRng = .Find(What:="U1", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)        
    If Not FndRng Is Nothing Then ' <-- Find was successful
        MsgBox "Found `U1` at row " & FndRng.Row
    Else
        MsgBox "Unable to find `U1`"
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Excel is pretty weird I used  With Sheet2.Range("B:G") instead of With Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:DZU") and it works but I will combine my codes with your codes. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful

```
Sub GetRowNum()
    Dim myValue As String
    myValue = "x"

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Debug.Print ws.Range("A:Z").Find(myValue).Row

End Sub
```

Edit: added `print` for visualisation